# MapView, fixed size of OverlayItem drawable

Tags: android, android-mapview, marker

I use osmdroid which is based on Google Map API v1. When I zoom in/out the map my markers are scaling accordingly but I want them to have fixed size. So how can I prevent scaling of a Drawable (used as a marker of OverlayItem) when I zoom in/out the map?

I create Drawable for the marker using BitmapDrawable(scaledBitmap)

Answer (score 0):

for fix size u add a popupview on a geopoint which is fix size by setting view params and set this drawable as a background

```
View popUp = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.map_popup, map, false);
MapView map = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);   
MapView.LayoutParams mapParams = new     MapView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    <geopoint>,
                    <x offset if required>,
                    <y offset like pinHeight>,
                    MapView.LayoutParams.BOTTOM_CENTER);
map.addView(popUp, mapParams);
```

Comment: Is this the only solution? I would really like to stay with the OverlayItem element. Maybe I can use BitmapFactory.Options;        opts.inScaled = false; on the existing bitmap? Is this possible?